# Why is this NP complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

I am looking at the diverse subset problem in Kleinberg and Tardos, shown in the image:

[image]

Why can't we give a polynomial time algorithm for this? Cant we iterate through each person a, and then each item i, and then see for each person b $\neq$ a if b has bought item i, then conclude that a and b cannot be diverse? And if we get through all items and no item that a has bought has been bought by b therefore implies they're diverse? Then we do this with each customer. What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Hint, $k$ could be something like $m/4$. Your brute force searching may run exponential steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you described isn't polynomial time because it has to consider every possible *subset* of customers (they are $2^m$ of these).

#### Solution

This problem is NP-hard because the vertex cover problem can be reduced to it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#Computational_problem

HINT: To do the reduction, consider how you would model $A$ as a graph and vice-versa. Once you've done that, consider how a "diverse set" is related to a vertex cover in the graphs.